# SharePoint site logo is too black in Hot Network Questions sidebar

Tags: bug, design, hot-questions, logo, sidebar

The logo of SharePoint site is just too black in the sidebar:

> [image]

Can this please be changed to something else, e.g. bright blue? (#D1EBFF in my example)

> [image]

Worth to mention, that on retina display or when zooming the page, the background is transparent.

Comment: I vote for a pink background.

Comment: Only on certain days, @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. ;)

Comment: Why do you think that level of black is "too" black? This doesn't seem like a bug, it seems like an opinion.

Comment: @TylerH no other icon is black, and as I mentioned it becomes white (transparent) at retina display.